# Declaring std::map constants

Tags: c++, stl

How to declare std map constants i.e.,

```
int a[10] = { 1, 2, 3 ,4 };
std::map <int, int> MapType[5] = { };
int main()
{
}
```

In the about snippet it is possible to give values 1,2,3,4 to integer array **a**, similarly how to declare some constant **MapType** values instead of adding values inside main() function.

Comment: You realize that you declare an array of 5 `std::map<int, int>`?

Comment: @Fritschy: that way you can have less elements in each map and the lookup will be faster... ;-)

Comment: @Tony, havent thought of it that way, good point ;)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

UPDATE: with C++11 onwards you can...

```
std::map<int, int> my_map{ {1, 5}, {2, 15}, {-3, 17} };
```

...or similar, where each pair of values - e.g. `{1, 5}` - encodes a key - `1` - and a mapped-to value - `5`.  The same works for `unordered_map` (a hash table version) too.

---

Using just the C++03 Standard routines, consider:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

typedef std::map<int, std::string> Map;

const Map::value_type x[] = { std::make_pair(3, "three"),
                              std::make_pair(6, "six"),
                              std::make_pair(-2, "minus two"), 
                              std::make_pair(4, "four") };

const Map m(x, x + sizeof x / sizeof x[0]);

int main()
{
    // print it out to show it works...
    for (Map::const_iterator i = m.begin();
            i != m.end(); ++i)
        std::cout << i->first << " -> " << i->second << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 7):

In C++0x, it will be:

```
map<int, int> m = {{1,2}, {3,4}};
```

Answer (score 1):

I was so taken by the [Boost.Assign](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/assign/doc/index.html) solution to this problem that I wrote a blog post about it about a year and a half ago (just before I gave up on blogging):

The relevant code from the post was this:

```
#include <boost/assign/list_of.hpp>
#include <map>

static std::map<int, int>  amap = boost::assign::map_list_of
    (0, 1)
    (1, 1)
    (2, 2)
    (3, 3)
    (4, 5)
    (5, 8);


int f(int x)
{
    return amap[x];
}
```